# Python how can I remove the floating point from numbers included within a field having string values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing fields having numbers with string and empty values like the in the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
new_row = [{'Col1': 1.0, 'Col2': 'c', 'Col3': 1.02}, {'Col1': 1.0, 'Col2': 'e', 'Col3': ''}]
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

The dataframe:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3

1.0     c       2.0

1.0     e
```

I need to remove `.0` from fields having strings as well, so the dataframe should look like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3

1.0     c       2

1.0     e
```

It is not only for `col3` because I have a huge real life dataframe. I tried the following:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: f'{x: .0f}')
```

And it returned an error:

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

So how can I remove the floating point from numbers included within a field having string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace `.0` only for columns with mixed values strings and numbers with `.0` use:

```
#data was changed for match sample data with 2.0 in Col3
df = pd.DataFrame()
new_row = [{'Col1': 1.0, 'Col2': 'c', 'Col3': 2.0}, {'Col1': 1.0, 'Col2': 'e', 'Col3': ''}]
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns

df[c] = df[c].astype(str).replace('\.0$','', regex=True)
print (df)
   Col1 Col2 Col3
0   1.0    c    2
1   1.0    e
```

If need processing all values:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return f'{x: .0f}'
    except:
        return x

df = df.applymap(f)
print (df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    1    c    2
1    1    e
```

Solution with test floats like integers (end by `.0`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
new_row = [{'Col1': 1.15, 'Col2': 'c', 'Col3': 2.0}, {'Col1': 1.064, 'Col2': 'e', 'Col3': ''}]
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

def f(x):
    try:
        if x.is_integer():
            return f'{x: .0f}'
        else:
            return x
    except:
        return x

df = df.applymap(f)
print (df)

    Col1 Col2 Col3
0  1.150    c    2
1  1.064    e
```

Comment: The first part worked just fine but in some case if a number is like `37.0899` it will be as `37.0899899`

Comment: @alim1990 - Not understand - `37.0899` is converted to `37.0899899` ? Or need `37.0899899` ?

Comment: all values having floating points are being doubled is it because of `$`?

Comment: `$` means end of string, I am sure it is not reason for doubled.

Comment: @alim1990 - so it means only replace `.0` if strings end with it, else not.

Comment: @alim1990 - added solution working with floats, but still not 1005 sure if understand what need.

Comment: oh sorry it is a CSV related stuff

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution

```
convert = lambda x: '%.0f' % x if isinstance(x,float) else x
df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].apply(convert)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want a string in your dataframe you cam use the try and ask for forgiveness pattern

```
def truncate(x):
    try:
        return '{0:1.0f}'.format(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

Unfortunately I cannot test this directly on a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this code:

```
df.astype(int)
```